# tocloft list of items in a textpos environnement

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, tocloft, textpos

I created a personal list with `tocloft` package. Here is the beginning of code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\pagestyle{empty}

\newcommand{\listMyItemsname}{My List of Items}

\newlistof{MyItems}{exp}{\listMyItemsname}

\newcommand{\MyItem}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{MyItems}
\par\noindent\textbf{#1}
\addcontentsline{exp}{MyItems}
{#1}\par}
```

and I would like the list of content of this list (imported from an external file) to be located at a special place in a textblock envronnement from the `textpos` package.

```
\begin{document}

\begin{textblock*}{190mm}[0,0](0mm,80mm)
\listMyItemsname
\end{textblock*}

\MyItem{item A}
\MyItem{item B}
\MyItem{item C}

\end{document}
```

The problem is, after compiling, I get :

[image]

and, I would like to obtain something like this :

[image]

Normaly, the `\listMyItemsname` command should print the list of contents of `MyItems` like `\tableofcontent` and show the items entry in list.

**Do you know what is wrong with my code ?**

---

*Note that I want my items to be read in an external file **after** the textblock environnement and I wish to generate the list of content of several lists in differents text blocks*

Comment: You're positioning the textblock on the page which is completely independent of the text, even if the `\MyItem` commands appear later. The textblock will even be overprinted if there are more `\MyItem` usages. I don't think `textpos` is really useful here. And you should use `\listofMyItems`, not `\listMyItemsname`

Comment: Are there any news here?